# How to copy a list into another list

Tags: vb.net, list

I make a code that compare real time value. This value is downloaded by internet page. In my code I've two list, in particular the following:
**lista** => save the updated value
**vecchia_lista** => save a copy of lista
in my code I go to run a "check code" that checking if a particular result is changed. Now I've a problem with the copy, infact, I copy the list like:
vecchia_lista = lista
but I searched on stackoverflow that this isn't a good way, because is a deep copy. So I found in the web this solution:

```
vecchia_lista = lista.Select(Function(innerList) vecchia_lista.ToList).ToList
```

the compiler tell me: 
**"System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of proj.frm.Country_Data))" in "System.Collections.Generic.List(Of proj.frm.Country_Data)"**

I'm trying to copy the contents of the "list" in "vecchia_lista", what am I doing wrong? I think maybe you might want to know the type of lists:

```
Dim lista As New List(Of Country_Data)
Dim vecchia_lista As New List(Of Country_Data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question: you need a copy of `lista` created into a new list `vecchia_lista`. This being the case, you could just do this:

```
Dim vecchia_lista As New List(Of Country_Data)

' Convert the contents of "lista" to an array and then merge into "vecchia_lista".
vecchia_lista.AddRange(lista.ToArray)
```

Comment: It's not a "deep clone" of the list though. So the objects in both lists reference to the same objects. Also you can omit the `ToArray` bit, as a list already implements `IEnumerable`. You can even use one of the overloaded constructors, which accept an `IEnumerable` as a parameter.